# How to write fractions in a uitextview for an iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to type fractions in a uitextview. I am using ios 7. 
I would like to type in something like this :

This 2x+5 / 5x+10 is a fraction. 
Example : http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cliffsnotes.com%2Fassets%2F255708.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cliffsnotes.com%2Fmath%2Falgebra%2Falgebra-ii%2Frational-expressions%2Fcomplex-fractions&h=182&w=180&tbnid=PEROMYA8fACPSM%3A&zoom=1&docid=oMP1S5fjqihpQM&hl=en&ei=mJtHU4TzIIiErAf4ooCADQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CKYBEIQcMBg&iact=rc&dur=157&page=2&start=16&ndsp=14

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView supports only text. You can try to use symbols "_", "-" with different font size formatting but I do not think it will work. I suggest you to look at UIWebView (you can write web page using HTTP/JS/CSS and feed it UIWebView) or search for a third party libraries.

Comment: Hi, Still stuck up with this. Using attributed strings on UITextView in ios7. used this function - (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return 20; // For really wide spacing; pick your own value
} to increase line height ...... I would like to place text one below the other (as we write for fractions) in the same line..... Is that possible at all? Cannot use UIWebView because it is an editor of sorts. Thanx in advance